# Pandoc: how to add line numbers to code blocks with docx output

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to enable line numbers with docx output to no avail:

```
~~~~ {#mycode .haskell .numberLines startFrom="100"}
qsort []     = []
qsort (x:xs) = qsort (filter (< x) xs) ++ [x] ++
               qsort (filter (>= x) xs)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

pandoc test.md -o build/test.docx

Is there anything special to do to enable line numbering for docx output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc does not support this out of the box, and neither does Word (as far as I know).

One could try to use a [filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) to add line numbers directly into the source text. The filter could also create a numbered list, where each item contains a single line of code. However, this might result in issues with highlighting or indentation, YMMV.

Comment: OK I will try your approach by modifying one of the existing filters

Comment: With word you can add numbers to the document. However one approach would be to enable this only for certain styles such as "Source Code", which is the style definition pandoc uses